# Real number on gawk

Tags: cmd, batch-file, geography, gawk

I am using gawk on a windows computer with cygwin.
What i am trying to do is find min and max from three columns, two are lat and lon and the third column is the value.

This is the code:

```
echo off    
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in    
  ('gawk "BEGIN {maxc = 0} {maxlo=0} {maxla=0}    
   {if ($3>maxc) maxc=$3} {if ($1>maxlo) maxlo=$1} {if ($2>maxla) maxla=$2} END    
   {print maxc, maxlo, maxla}" %file%.projected')    
do (
  set maxc=%%a    
  set maxlo=%%b    
  set maxla=%%c    
)
echo max is %maxc%
echo max is %maxla%
echo max is %maxlo%

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in    
 ('gawk "BEGIN {minc =1000} {minlo=1000} {minla=1000}    
  {if ($3<minc) minc=$3} {if ($1<minlo) minlo=$1} {if ($2<minla) minla=$2} END    
  {print minc, minlo, minla}" %file%.projected')    
do (
  set minc=%%a    
  set minlo=%%b    
  set minla=%%c    
)    
echo min %minc%    
echo min %minla%    
echo min %minlo%
```

What i get is:

```
max is 465.053890    
max latitude is 31.846428    
max is 34.877658    
min 19.976970    
min 31.846428    
min 34.877658
```

The min and max are the same for the lon and lat.
How can i compare real numbers?

Comment: can you maybe add some line feeds and such to make the code more intelligible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that this line

```
'gawk "BEGIN {minc =1000} {minlo=1000} {minla=1000}
```

doesn't do what you think it does. (Frankly, I'm astounded it compiled at all, I don't think it would have in Kernighan AWK.)  And a lot of what's going on here is actually in, what, a Window `BAT` file?

But here are some guesses.

- I think the line I quoted above sets `minc` at start time, and then sets `minlo` and `minla` *every time* it reads a line.  Better would be

.

```
 'BEGIN { minc = 1000; minlo = 1000; minla = 1000; } ....
```

or even

```
 'BEGIN { minc = minlo = minla = 1000; } ....
```

- in AWK you have to watch out a little with comparisons, because if you aren't careful it coerces your numbers to string and does a string compare (ie lexicographic ordering) instead of a numeric compare.

Ack, tried to do this as an answer to a comment.  No go.

The reason the first line doesn't work is that AWK lines have the form

```
PATTERN { code }
```

where PATTERN is some expression that identifies a set of input records (usually lines) on which the code part operates.  There are some special cases, for example `BEGIN`, which "matches" before the first time is read.  Another special case is the empty pattern, which matches every line.  So what you had was being interpreted as

```
BEGIN {minc  =1000}
      {minlo =1000}
      {minla =1000}
```

So, before the first line of input is processed, `minc` is set to 1000.  *Following* that, on *every* input line, `minlo` and `minla` are set to 1000.  My versions, since they all do the initialization in a `BEGIN` line, just initialize the values once.

Comment: why is the first gawk line OK? the one that finds the maximum?